# IdentityServer database changes for scenarios

Tags: oauth, openid, identityserver3, identityserver4

I am trying to put together some documentation on changes that need to be made to the Database back-end when different actions are performed so they can operate with IdentityServer4, but realizing that I am not sure what items in the database are affected when you perform actions like (adding a new user, adding a new client, and a scope, etc..)  I am using this to get a better understanding of how all the elements work together, and how to relate to each other - See below which I am needing to expand on.
Can anyone with good experience with IdentityServer backend help me?

```
[Adding a new user]
```

- add a record to dbo.AspNetUsers – All user pertaining information.
- add a record to dbo.AspNetUserClaims – Identifying information stored similar to Key/Value Pair set with a reference pointing to the User

```
[Adding a new Client – (Controller Web API Endpoint)]
```

-  add a record to dbo.Clients – Details that define the client
-  add a record to dbo.ClientGrantTypes – All grant types allowed for authorization to the specified client.
-  add a record to dbo.ClientSecrets – Password and secret information pertaining to the client.
-   add a record to dbo.ClientScopes – Scope name matched to the ClientId for allowing.  You will need to add scope(s) for the client so it can be accessed.
-?? Not sure how IdentityResoure and IdentityClaims are used here, and also how oidc ones are used here.

?? What is the difference between Api and Client in Identity Server DB?

```
[New Claim type is added, and needs to be included in the data returned with the JWT token]
```

...

Answer (score 0):

use `IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity` for storing users in SQL Server using EF http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html

use `IdentityServer4.EntityFramework` for storing clients and resources configuration in SQL Server using EF.
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/8_entity_framework.html

Look into the [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/) repository for code samples.